# On the definition of Error-Correcting Codes

Tags: coding-theory, error-correcting-codes, algebra, definitions

Let us start with the following well-known definition:

> ***Definition 1.*** Let $C\subseteq A^n$ be a code over $A$ and let $t\in \Bbb Z^+$ be a positive integer.  We say that the code $C$ is
> $\boldsymbol t$**-error correcting** if nearest neighbour decoding is
> able to correct at most $t$ errors, assuming that if a tie occurs in
> the decoding process, a decoding error is reported. That is, if
> whenever $x \in C$ and $y\in A^n$ such that $\mathrm{d}(x,y)\leq t$, then $y$ is decoded to $x$
> using nearest neighbour decoding.

Now let us make an observation.

> ***Remark.***  Recall that when there is no unique nearest codeword to $x\in C$, then
> nearest neighbour decoding *fails*. So, a code $C\subseteq A^n$ is $t$-error correcting if and only if
> whenever $y\in A^n$ is a word within distance $t$ of a codeword $x\in
>   C$ (that is, $\mathrm{d}(x,y)\leq t$), then $$\mathrm{d}(x,y) <
>   \mathrm{d}(z,y), \quad \text{for all } x\neq z \in C.$$

The Remark gives us a more ***abstract** way to state the definition* of $t$-error correcting without  mentioning nearest neighbour decoding.

However, I stumbled on another statement of the definition (which I found on some lecture notes on the web):

> ***Definition 2.*** The code $C$ is $t$**-error correcting** if there do not exist $x,z \in C$ such that $x\neq z$ and $y\in A^n$ such that
> $$\mathrm d(x, y)\leq t, \quad \mathrm d (z, y)\leq t.$$

**My question is why the last definition is equivalent to the first one (given with the form of the remark).**

*Could you please give me a hand?*

---

UPDATE: My attempt: Definition 1 tells us that
$$(\forall x\in C)(\forall z \in C)(\forall y\in A^n)(d(x,y)\leq t)(z\neq x \implies d(x,y)<d(z,y)).$$

Definition 2 tells us that
$$(\forall x\in C)(\forall z \in C)(\forall y\in A^n)(d(x,y)\leq t)(d(z,y)\leq t \implies z=x).$$
Equivalently,
$$(\forall x\in C)(\forall z \in C)(\forall y\in A^n)(d(x,y)\leq t)(z\neq x\implies d(z,y)>t ).$$
Equivalently,
$$(\forall x\in C)(\forall z \in C)(\forall y\in A^n)(d(x,y)\leq t)(z\neq x\implies d(z,y)>t\geq d(x,y)).$$
So the Def2 $\implies$ Def 1. Is that correct? How about $\Longleftarrow$?

Comment: The definitions are equivalent. I suggest spending more time on the matter.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Please check my edit :)

Comment: As you can see, it’s only a small manipulation to go from one definition to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the remark says:

> A code $C \subseteq A^n$ is $t$-error-correcting if for all $x \in C$ and $y \in A^n$ such that $d(x,y) \leq t$, all $z \in C$ other than $x$ satisfy $d(x,y) < d(z,y)$.

When is a code *not* $t$-error-correcting according to this remark?

> A code $C \subseteq A^n$ is *not* $t$-error-correcting if there exist $x,z \in C$ and $y \in A^n$ such that $x \neq z$ and $d(z,y) \leq d(x,y) \leq t$.

Given $x,y,z$, either $d(z,y) \leq d(x,y)$ or $d(x,y) \leq d(z,y)$, and so, since the other constraints on $x,z$ are symmetric in $x,z$, the above definition is equivalent to

> A code $C \subseteq A^n$ is *not* $t$-error-correcting if there exist $x,z \in C$ and $y \in A^n$ such that $x \neq z$ and $d(x,y),d(z,y) \leq t$.

This is exactly Definition 2.

Comment: Thanks for your simple and clear answer. So, in other words, given that $d(x,y),d(z,y) \leq t$, either $d(x,y)\leq d(z,y) \leq t$ or $d(z,y) \leq d(x,y) \leq t$, which tells us how to go from 2. to 1. Right?

Comment: Right, that's the idea.

Comment: Dr Filmus, many thanks.